# Is there a protocol associated with Swift's .description?

Tags: swift

Since Swift 2 (3?) the "right way" to get a textual output from any old object is to use `.description`. I'd like to use `.description` in a generic function:

```
func checkNumeric<T>(_ value: T) -> Bool {
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .decimal
    return (nf.number(from:value.description) != nil)
}
```

But that doesn't work, because T doesn't support `.description` (which, IMHO, is a Very Bad Thing). In any event, is there a way to do this? There is `CustomStringConvertible`, but no `StringConvertible`, and I can't seem to find anything else similar.

Yes, I'm aware I can make my own protocol and add the classes to it with extensions. However, the *whole point* of this function is to avoid having to know and list every possible class that might go into the function.

Comment: what is wrong with `CustomStringConvertible`?

Comment: And why would T not having a `description` by default be "a Very Bad Thing", I have NEVER used description unless for debugging purposes, that is a very good reason not to have it being in my production code polluting memory.

Comment: @luk2302, doesn't CustomStringConvertable *only* apply to classes that have an explicit description method?

Comment: Since `description`s can be *anything*, such as the developer desires, and are not guaranteed to be the same across versions of iOS, I think this test is very brittle. That being said, @luk2302 is correct re: `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: @Tommy - any other suggestions on how to do this without being brittle? The alternatives I've seen are string tests that a fraught with localization peril, or "is X" with huge lists of classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assert that `T` must be any `CustomStringConvertible`, which will expose the `.description` property on `T`.

```
func checkNumeric<T>(_ value: T) -> Bool 
where T: CustomStringConvertible {
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .decimal
    return (nf.number(from:value.description) != nil)
}
```

If you are creating your own classes with a description property, just make sure they conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. Then there's no need to create your own protocol and extend every class that may or may not be used.

Comment: This does work with all my samples, I guess I should have just playgrounded it. @Tommy, I suspect for this test your concern is not a major one though - I find it difficult to believe numbers will not return a numeric string?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz potential failures off the top of my head: what if I've implemented my type always to use continental-style separators (e.g. 423.423,92) but you're running on an English-language machine, what if I've implemented a complex-number class that might print something like "3 + 2i" but if there's no imaginary part will just print "3"? What if my class in some way represents an `enum` and for now I just print the enum value, but later I switch to printing an actual descriptive string? What if I always print a number but the storage is a float so sometimes I print `NaN`?

Comment: Note that the documentation for [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) explicitly discourages against using it as a generic constraint (you really shouldn't care if the description comes from a custom implementation or not). You can get a textual description for *any* value in Swift through the `String(describing:)` initialiser or string interpolation; but of course those descriptions are implementation details and really not something you should be using here to begin with (as Tommy says above).

Comment: These are all fair comments @Tommy, but they also apply to all the other solutions I've seen - specifically, looking for key characters such that "5.10,10.10" would pass, or using "is Double", which requires you to enumerate all past, present and future numerics. If you have a better solution to this problem, trust me, **I'm all ears**!